# RoR Michael Hartl 9.33 Pagination not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

**index.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
      <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
```

I have restarted the server. I have installed the necessary gems, double checked that they were installed with 'gem list'. For some reason my index page still has no pagination. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

In the index action of your controller where you are setting the instance variable `@users`, make sure to call `paginate` method. For example:

```
  def index
    @users = User.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end
```

You can change the value of `per_page` option as per your requirement.
Read about **[How to use paginate method](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate#basic-will_paginate-use)** here

**UPDATE**

In the `index.html.erb` view,

Replace

```
<%= will_paginate %>
```

With

```
<%= will_paginate @users %>
```

Comment: Ok still no pagination, but at least now there are 10 users instead of all.

Comment: Well, that means pagination is working. You can't get all as we have limited `:per_page => 10`.

Comment: No but where are the links?